# How to use Unicode to print symbols in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to print symbols in dart language using only Unicode something like U+20B9 and not escape sequence(\u20B9). I am used below dart code. Is there any way to print the symbols using only Unicode?I am using Unicode from this website https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html

```
void main(){
  print('\u20B9');//escape sequence
  print("U+20B9");//Unicode
}
```

output

```
₹
U+20B9
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following package on
[pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)

:`characters: ^1.2.0`

[link](https://pub.dev/packages/characters)

Comment: Hey @ruchit I don't want to use any packages, is there any way?